# How do i make a command handler that'll scan the folders too?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot so, I have made way too many commands now I need to put them in their own folders like moderation, misc, etc.

```js
const commandFlies = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));


for (const file of commandFlies) {
    const command = require(`./commands/misc/${file}`);

    // set a new item in the Collection
    // with the key as the command name and the value as the exported value
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

const client = new Discord.Client();
const cooldowns = new Discord.Collection();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFlies = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));


for (const file of commandFlies) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    // set a new item in the Collection
    // with the key as the command name and the value as the exported value
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

It keeps telling me that it's already defined.

Comment: Could you give us the exact error message

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I've already fixed it but thank you for trying!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you were able to fix it!